# Custom Bing Map Type Issue

Tags: bing-maps

I'm having a problem trying to correct for this. I have created 2 custom Bing map types. The user can change the map type through a custom drop box. When the user changes from Default to Road. A majority of the time if the user changes back to Default, the roads stay. Am I missing something so obvious. I've included my code.

**Map Types**

```
var defaultMapColors =
        {
            "version": "1.0",
            "settings":
                {
                    "landColor": "#686868"
                },
            "elements":
                {
                    "mapElement": { "labelVisible": false },
                    "area": { "visible": false },
                    "transportation": { "visible": false },
                    "countryRegion": {                          //country
                        "borderStrokeColor": "#444444",
                        "borderOutlineColor": "#00000000",
                        "borderWidthScale": 3,
                        "fillColor": "#888888",
                        "visible": true
                    },
                    "adminDistrict": {                          //states
                        "borderVisible": true,
                        "borderStrokeColor": "#444444",
                        "borderOutlineColor": "#00000000",
                        "borderWidthScale": 3,
                        "fillColor": "#888888",
                    },
                    "water": { "fillColor": "#4E5E6D" },
                    "point": { "visible": false }
                }
        };

    var defaultMapColorsWithRoads =
        {
            "version": "1.0",
            "settings":
                {
                    "landColor": "#686868"
                },
            "elements":
                {
                    "mapElement": { "labelVisible": false },
                    "area": { "visible": false },
                    "transportation": {
                        "visible": true,
                        "strokeColor": "#ffffff",
                    },
                    "countryRegion": {                          //country
                        "borderStrokeColor": "#444444",
                        "borderOutlineColor": "#00000000",
                        "borderWidthScale": 3,
                        "fillColor": "#888888",
                        "visible": true
                    },
                    "adminDistrict": {                          //states
                        "borderVisible": true,
                        "borderStrokeColor": "#444444",
                        "borderOutlineColor": "#00000000",
                        "borderWidthScale": 3,
                        "fillColor": "#888888",
                    },
                    "water": { "fillColor": "#4E5E6D" },
                    "point": { "visible": false }
                }

        };
```

**Drop Down**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <select id="customNavSelector" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick">
            <option value="Default" onclick="map.setView({ mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, customMapStyle: defaultMapColors });">Default</option>
            <option value="Road" onclick="map.setView({ mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, customMapStyle: defaultMapColorsWithRoads });">Road</option>
            <option value="Aerial" onclick="map.setView({ mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial, customMapStyle: '' });">Aerial</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**Map Object**

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(mapDiv,
                    {
                        credentials: "@ViewBag.BingMapKey",
                        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CenterLatitude"], @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CenterLongitude"]),
                        customMapStyle: defaultMapColors,
                        mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road, //grayscale, aerial, road, canvasLight, canvasDark
                        //liteMode: true,
                        showMapTypeSelector: false, //set to true to show default bing map selector
                        disableStreetside: false,
                        disableStreetsideAutoCoverage: true,
                        zoom: zoom,
                        backgroundColor: 'black',
                        //showBreadcrumb: true,
                        //showLocateMeButton: locator,
                        enableInertia: false,
                        enableClickableLogo: false,
                        navigationBarMode: Microsoft.Maps.NavigationBarMode.compact     //compact, default, minified
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue where setting the map style merges the new style with the old style instead of overwriting it completely. The team plans to fix this. In the mean time, if you dispose the current map and create a new instance of the map with the map style it will work as expected.

Comment: I dont think I am able to do this.  this is for an internal map application with multiple layers being added to the map.  disposing the map would cause the user to lose their current data if they switched from one map type to the other based on your suggestion - correct?

Comment: Correct, however you could track which layers are turned on an simply add them to the new map instance.

Comment: I did try this just to see if it would work.  it does.  However, for what we need it for it is not 100% realistic.  For now, we are going to forego the the road selction for now till a fix is available